# Word: How to find all years (19xx or 20xx) ending with a closing parenthesis ")"

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, find

I'm helping someone do a two-way citation check in an academic paper.

What I would like to do is use the Find function to find all instances of citations; all citations should have this format

(Author 20xx) or (Author 19xx)
"Author" can be multiple Authors such as (AuthorA, AuthorB 2019) or (AuthorA et al. 2019), but always follows with one space after the author and before the year (19xx or 20xx), followed with a closing parenthesis.

Is there a quick way to find all "year" strings, specifically years that end with ")"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.
2. On the "Find what" box, enter: `[12][90][0-9][0-9]\)`
3. Click on More, then enable "Use wildcards"

**Explanation:**

- `[12]`: value stating with 1 or 2
- `[90]`: values 9 or 0
- `[0-9][0-9]`: finds values that ranges from 00-99
- `\)`: finds the parenthesis

**Edit:** Based on correct comments by @Toto that the above will also find 1000 or 2099 (dates that are not the OP is not searing for), 2 searches will need to be done. The first for 19xx and the second for 20xx.

- For 19xx: search for `19[0-9][0-9]\)`
- For 20xx: search for `20[0-2][0-9]\)`

`19[0-9][0-9]` will find years from 1900 to 1999 while `20[0-2][0-9]` will find from 2000 to 2029.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: This is also matching `1000` or `2999`.